# how to access session in view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, spark-view-engine

I use MVC 3 with spark view engine. I have a data that should be accessed in every pages, the data base-on user login information. so I collect the data when user loged in and I put it on a session. I use a control to handle the data in site master ( master page ). and data in session will be binded to that control (eg. Dropdownlist ).

is it the best practise to handle data in master page on asp.net MVC ?
I try to create a base class for controller, buat I can't hold the login credential (HttpContext.User.Identity).
how can I access session data from View ?

I try to use @Session["mydata"] ( !{Session["mydata"] in spark view engine} but it didn't works :(

any helps ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two general ways to handle this.
One is to use Html.RenderAction from your layout (master page). In that way you are packaging all of your data ahead of time into a model the master page will use.

The second way is to have your controllers inherit from another controller. When the base controller is instantiated, it is responsible for populating ViewData with the required data which is then displayed on the page. This requires all of your controllers to inherit from your base controller. 
See listing 4/5 at:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs

You could also do this via an action filter (and other ways too!!) but I think the above two ways are a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get to the credential of the logged on user by calling System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name in your controller base class.

That should allow you to populate the ViewData and then access the data from your view.

Alternatively if you still want to use the session,  you should be able to access the session via - HttpContext.Current.Session["mydata"]

Comment: thanks Naraen for System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use TempData["name"] for sharing data on different actions in a controller. Remember once value is retrieved, it will delete the data but you can use .Peek and .Keep method functionality to store its value